# how to solve a unexpected found nil in swift using dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Sorry i know it must be easy to solve that but i have no idea how. Could anyone help me?[image]

```
//Gesamtpausen
var pauses:[Double]=[]
for learnunit in learnunits {
    pauses.append(learnunit.totalPauseTime!)
}
//GesamtLernzeit
var studying:[Double]=[]
for learnunit in learnunits {
    studying.append(learnunit.totalStudyingTime!)
}
```

Comment: your totalPauseTime is nil

Comment: You should always post the code not a screenshot, and your are trying to unwrap something that is nil or empty

Comment: is there any option to solve that? i mean i know that some older data has the totalPauseTime nil. anyways i want to add up the ones that are not nil

Comment: var pauses: [Double] = []
var studying: [Double] = []

learnUnits.forEach { (learnunit) in
    if let pauseTime = learnunit.totalPauseTime {
        pauses.append(pauseTime)
    }
    if let studyingTime = learnunit.totalStudyingTime {
        studying.append(studyingTime)
    }
}

Comment: You can simplify this to one line of each: `let totalPause = learnUnits.flatMap { $0.totalPauseTime }.reduce(0.0, +)`. The `flatMap` unwraps the values, discarding those that are nil. The `reduce(0.0, +)` adds them up for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if let pauseTime = learnunit.totalPauseTime {
    pauses.append(pauseTime)
}
```